# How to detect of a requested URL contains query string?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to detect if a requested URL contains query string or not.
How can I do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly use [getQueryString()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString()) method

OR

You can check if your url has a query string or not by splitting it on "?" or finding index of the "?" character.

On splitting, your result array must have atleast length greater than 1 and if you take the index route, then the index must be greater than 0 since first character cant be a "?" assuming you will have correct url entered to check for query string.

Answer (score 4):

Something like `requestedUrl.indexOf("?") > 0` should do. Because query string parameters are passed by appending ? to the url and then name/value pairs follow.